# Chainable function does not run in predicted sequence

Tags: javascript, animation, method-chaining

I have a chainable function, it's simple, I pass the values to animate  it a certain amount of pixels. If I only call one method of the object, it works sometimes, including the animation. If I try to chain the 2 methods, it just applies one of the translations (the second) and always without animation.This is the function:

```
var block = document.getElementById('mickeyBlock');
var animateBlock = {
    currentBlock: block,
    moveX: function(distance) {
        this.currentBlock.style.transform = 'translateX(' + distance + ')';
        return this;
    },
    currentBlock: block,
    moveY: function(distance) {
        this.currentBlock.style.transform = 'translateY(' + distance + ')';
        return this;
    }
}
window.onload = animateBlock.moveX('300px').moveY('10px');
```

I have tried to pass the second method as callback, did not work(maybe I did it wrong). However, this should be chainable, thus, without a need to pass the second method as callback.

Why is this happening, does this need a transitionend listener somewhere?

Here is the link:

https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/MvvXoq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To combine two transformations, use += instead of = in the transform assignment

The `transform` applied second is overwriting the one applied first. To avoid this, change

```
this.currentBlock.style.transform = 'translateX(' + distance + ')';
```

to

```
this.currentBlock.style.transform += 'translateX(' + distance + ')';
```

and similarly for the `translateY`.

#### There is a duplication of a line of code

Not relevant to your problem, but `currentBlock: block,` is present twice.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, however, it was initially not running animated, it just jumped to the final spot. Then I called the fn onclick in a callback, smoothness now:-) Thanks, this is a major breakthrough